# Is there any reason to use the Switch Axe's axe mode in MH: Rise?

Tags: monster-hunter-rise

Is there any other reason to use the Switch Axe's axe mode? Normally, the Switch Axe's axe mode would be used to refill your switch meter, which you need to have up to use sword mode. However, this time around, you can just instantly refill your switch meter using a wirebug skill. Is there some other effect of axe mode that I am missing out on by using sword mode almost exclusively and refilling my meter using a wirebug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious answer would be that axe mode has a different moveset. Higher movement speed and longer reach are perfectly valid reasons to use axe mode, for example when using the X+A upswing to hit flying monsters.

There is also a powered up state that is only attainable through axe mode, by using at least three wild swings in a row (by pressing A), and finishing with a heavy slam (pressing X). In this powered up state, it is faster to enter amped state in sword mode.

Comment: I'm going to be 100% honest, I literally did not notice that you have higher movement speed with axe out vs sword.